# Angular 5 - Auto sound notification on data change

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a web application using Angular 5.
I have created web application and everything is working fine.
I have an order system where admin can see all the orders listed. When new order comes in, the order list gets updated automatically. That works fine. 
I want an auto alert system which will play simple sound when new order comes in automatically.
lets consider there are 8 orders listed in a table. A new order comes in and it shows 9 orders. That works. I want alert system when the 9th order get listed. 
Just like what email inbox generates auto desktop notification when new mail comes in automatically.
I am new to this.

here is html code

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Customer</th>
      <th>Date</th>      
      <th>Status</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead> 
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let order of filteredOrders | reverse" >
      <td>{{ order.shipping.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ order.datePlaced | date}}</td>
        <td>{{ order.orderStatus }}</td>
      <td>
        <a [routerLink]="['/admin/orders/', order.$key]">View</a> 
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody> 
</table>
```

may be ngOnchanges will help but not sure how to implement it in actual component.ts .
If anybody has any example then that will help.
Thanks

EDIT.
Below is the TS code.

```
import { Order } from './../../models/order';
import { OrderService } from './../../order.service';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../login/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-orders',
  templateUrl: './admin-orders.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-orders.component.css']
})
export class AdminOrdersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges {
  orders: any[];
  filteredOrders: any[];
  subscription: Subscription;
  user: firebase.User;
  user$;    

  constructor(private orderService: OrderService,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService) {
    this.subscription = this.orderService.getOrders().subscribe(orders =>
      this.filteredOrders = this.orders = orders);
    afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(user => this.user$ = user);
  }  

  filter(query: string) {
    this.filteredOrders = (query) ?
      this.orders.filter(p => p.orderStatus.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) :
      this.orders;
  }

  filterAll() {
    this.subscription = this.orderService.getOrders().subscribe(orders =>
      this.filteredOrders = this.orders = orders);
  }

  ngOnInit() {    
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {    

  }   

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }    

}
```

Comment: Please show your ts code

Comment: [This example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_snackbar.asp) shows how to add a toast notification to your webpage. Is that what you want?